# How to resolve respond code 406 erro in java?

Tags: java, json, https, outlook

I able making a rest call using the microsoft outlook api. This is the code I have written.

```
public static void sendGet() {

    String url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/Inbox/messages";
    final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json";
    final String ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = "en-US,en;q=0.8";

    try {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", ACCEPT_LANGUAGE);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic c2h1YW5nQHZpdfdGVjaGluYydf5jb2fdXjhNCE="); //base64 encoding of auth username:password

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("response code: " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am trying to return a json response containing all the messages in my inbox, but it's returning an IO Exception with error code 406.

[image]

I am pretty sure that the content-type "application/json" is supported and when I perform the rest call using post man it will able to successfully return me the json data.

From the postman header, the content-type of application/json was supported. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding `Accept: application/json` to the HTTP header.

`Accept` header is used by HTTP clients to tell the server what content types they accept. The server then sends back a response, which includes a `Content-Type` header telling the client what the content type of the returned content actually is.

tldr; `Accept` is what the client is able to consume and `Content-Type` is what the data actually is.

Comment: what is the different between accept and content-type. I thought content-type: application/json will work.

Comment: @mrtofu The content-type header describes the content *you* are sending, whilst the accept header is about the content you expect to receive from the server.

Answer (score 2):

> The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

In other words, add the content type returned by the API to your accept header.